# Python (Pyserial) : What to do when serial gets hung up?

Tags: python, serial-port

In the code below, I am sending a message to some teensy (arduino) boards to help me dynamically identify them. The problem is, every once and a while, this code gets gets hung up (I'm assuming) when 'pot_port.read(1)' doesn't receive the byte it's looking for. How can I avoid this situation or, if it does get hung up, how can I fix it?

```
    for port in current_ports:
        if 'ACM' in port:
            print port
            pot_port = serial.Serial(port, BAUD_RATE, timeout=TIMEOUT)
            time.sleep(1)
            pot_port.write('#')
            time.sleep(1)
            response = pot_port.read(1)
            print response
            if response is 'a':
                matrix_port = pot_port
            elif response is 'b':
                led_port = pot_port
```

Update: I took some precautions to only call .read() if there was anything to read with this new code.

```
    for port in current_ports:
        if 'ACM' in port:
            print port
            pot_port = serial.Serial(port, BAUD_RATE, timeout=TIMEOUT)
            print pot_port.inWaiting()
            pot_port.flushInput()
            print pot_port.inWaiting()
            while pot_port.inWaiting() == 0:
                 pot_port.flushInput()
                 time.sleep(1)
                 pot_port.write('#')
                 time.sleep(1)
                 print pot_port.inWaiting()
            response = pot_port.read(1)
            pot_port.flushInput()
            print response
            if response is 'a':
                matrix_port = pot_port
            elif response is 'b':
                led_port = pot_port
```

Seems to be working great so far, if anyone has any suggestions though, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 0):

Checking inWaiting(), as you're doing, is one viable approach.

An approach I've used is to set TIMEOUT to a positive value, so that your .read(1) will give up and return an empty string if nothing is received within TIMEOUT seconds.

```
pot_port = serial.Serial(port, BAUD_RATE, timeout=10)
response = pot_port.read(1)
if response:
    do_something_useful()
else:
    fault_response()
```